# How should I restrict direct url access to a form mail script in perl-cgi?

Tags: apache, perl, centos

My project is running on a apache server on **CentOS**.

My project is one-page site that contains a form that send mail when submitted.

I wrote that form mail script in **Perl CGI**.

It is able to send mail when submitted but I want to restrict the direct URL access to that mail script.

How should I do, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Some people tell you that you can do it by looking at the HTTP Referer in the request. But that can be faked.